# Problemas Api Facebook cuando es ejecutada desde navegador de celular

Tags: android, jquery, login, facebook, google-chrome-app

Hice un *login* con facebook y anda perfecto en el navegador web pero cuando intento correrlo desde mi celular en *chrome android* dice que hay problemas con URL, la cual no permite la URI ingresada.
En la web de pc no pasa esto.
Alguien me puede aconsejar algo?

El **código** es el siguiente

```html
<!-- Display login status -->
<div id="status"></div>

<!-- Facebook login or logout button -->
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fbLogin()" id="fbLink">Iniciar</a>

<!-- Display user profile data -->
<div id="userData"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // FB JavaScript SDK configuration and setup
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'mi id de app', // FB App ID
      cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
      version    : 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.8
    });
    
    // Check whether the user already logged in
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            //display user data
            getFbUserData();
        }
    });
};

// Load the JavaScript SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

// Facebook login with JavaScript SDK
function fbLogin() {
    FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            // Get and display the user profile data
            getFbUserData();
        } else {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.';
        }
    }, {scope: 'email'});
}

// Fetch the user profile data from facebook
function getFbUserData(){
    FB.api('/me', {locale: 'en_US', fields: 'id,first_name,last_name,email,link,gender,locale,picture'},
    function (response) {
        document.getElementById('fbLink').setAttribute("onclick","fbLogout()");
        document.getElementById('fbLink').innerHTML = 'Logout from Facebook';
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.first_name + '!';
        document.getElementById('userData').innerHTML = '<p><b>FB ID:</b> '+response.id+'</p><p><b>Name:</b> '+response.first_name+' '+response.last_name+'</p><p><b>Email:</b> '+response.email+'</p><p><b>Gender:</b> '+response.gender+'</p><p><b>Locale:</b> '+response.locale+'</p><p><b>Picture:</b> <img src="'+response.picture.data.url+'"/></p><p><b>FB Profile:</b> <a target="_blank" href="'+response.link+'">click to view profile</a></p>';
    });
}

// Logout from facebook
function fbLogout() {
    FB.logout(function() {
        document.getElementById('fbLink').setAttribute("onclick","fbLogin()");
        document.getElementById('fbLink').innerHTML = '<img src="fblogin.png"/>';
        document.getElementById('userData').innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'You have successfully logout from Facebook.';
    });
}
</script>
```

En el navegador se ve correctamente el inicio, e inicia sesión naturalmente dando los datos del usuario.
En chrome para android sale la siguiente nota:

> **URL bloqueada:** La redirección falló porque la URI no está en la lista
>   incluida en la lista blanca de las preferencias OAuth de cliente de la
>   aplicación. Comprueba que el acceso OAuth de cliente y web estén
>   activados y agrega todos los dominios de tus aplicaciones como URI de
>   redirección OAuth.

Comment: desde chorme móvil la dirección es m.facebook.com, y en web es www.facebook.com, incluye m.facebook.com en tu WhiteList y dinos que pasa.

Comment: @L.Ronquillo white list es la lista de url en el developers de facebook??  O en donde esta dicha lista ?

Comment: debe de ser esa.

Comment: Disculpame.. Pero no entiendo soy nuevo en esto.. Debo modificar el script? La configuración de facebook? O configuración de celular?

Comment: Creo que lo tienes que hacer en developers de facebook en faceboo login , ahí puedes activar Client OAuth Login, Web OAuth Login

Comment: Lo he hecho, agregue mi dominio.. desde la pc anda excelente.. el problema esta desde el celular..

Comment: Cual es tu dominio, o estas trabajando como localhost?